# What would the impact of dramatic drop in temperature due to an asteroid strike be?

Tags: society, natural-disasters, post-apocalypse

Assume that an asteroid strikes earth somewhere in central Eurasia, kicking up enough dirt and ash into the atmosphere to darken the sun and cool the surface of the earth for a millennium. I know that the duration of the darkening is not realistic, but let's assume that it did happen. 
We are talking about maybe an average drop off 10 to 15 degrees Celsius initially which then gradually gets less as the cloud gets thinner.

Would modern civilization survive? Or would the change be quick and dramatic enough to essentially destroy it through famine and possibly war as nations struggle to acquire food to feed their starving population? Would we be able to counter such an effect with technology that can be developed fast enough?

Comment: How big and how massive is this asteroid?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_event#Impacts_and_the_Earth) is helpful.

Comment: You may also want to look into the effect from massive volcanic eruptions. A cooling period of 1,000 years is actually feasible, and we have been able to track the effects of these events through history. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_volcanic_eruptions_by_death_toll

Comment: Any advanced warning on the impact?..are the nations aware and able to prepare to survive, or is it a surprise?

Answer (score 2):

First, you want to assume something which does not make sense. To cool Earth by dust raised by asteroids, you cannot have single even but continuous bombardment every few years, not a one blow. Even then, dust will settle after few years, some of it in polar areas, decreasing Earth's albedo, and increasing melting the ice and warming the planet. So you will need to increase bombardment steadily to keep enough dust in air.

Also, to get to [Snowball earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_Earth) you don't need to decrease global temperature by 10-15 Celsius for a global disaster. And once if get that low, temperature will keep decreasing. Climate is substantially more fragile. As ice covers big part of polar regions (30 degrees from equator), Earth albedo increases, more sun's energy is reflected back to space, and cooling increases (positive [ice-albedo feedback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice-albedo_feedback) ). Because of positive feedback from albedo, temperature fell to -50C in snowball earth.

It's unlikely civilization will survive global average temperature of -50C. Some life would, tho.

But we have excellent way to fight such danger - just burn some more carbon, then roast.

During [Paleocene–Eocene Thermal Maximum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleocene%E2%80%93Eocene_Thermal_Maximum) 56MYA average temperature increased by around 6C (5C in polar areas) and because of ice-albedo feedback, all went to hell in a basket. Accidentally, that is exactly where we are heading if current carbon burning will not be significantly restricted.

Answer (score 1):

"Assume that an asteroid strikes earth ... and cool the surface of the earth for a millennium."

So, basically, you're looking at winter not ending for 1000 years, only it's even worse. With a 10-15 degree drop in average temperatures, summer turns into winter, and winter turns into super-winter. Trees die. Crops die. Livestock dies. People die, by the millions.

This isn't a gradual cooling over a few decades, it's *sudden instant crop failure all over the world*. All the worlds major staple crops (wheat, rice, soy, etc.) will fail. Grasslands die off too, which means sheep and cows die by the millions.

Maybe for the first year or two, people can grow a bit of food in greenhouses. But it's not enough. There's a world of difference between growing a few strawberries and tomatoes in greenhouses, and growing enough wheat or rice to prevent mass starvation.

People, of course, will not go out without a fight. They will riot, they will invade other countries. Wars will break out. Cities will burn, more smoke and ash will go into the atmosphere and reduce temperatures even more. And that's *without* any nuclear exchanges. Basically, they make things worse.

People will start burning all the wood they can find for heating, increasing the smoke in the atmosphere and *far* outweighing the increase in temperature due to CO2. (It's a trap: that CO2 is still in the atmosphere, building up, even as it is masked by the lowered temperatures from smoke and ash. Once the particulate matter washes out of the atmosphere, the transition to a high-temperature greenhouse world will be *really* fast.)

If the cold temperatures lasted three or four years, it would merely lead to enormous political upheavals. Like, half of Europe invading Africa. The collapse of cities into mass rioting when people can't buy bread for the third week in a row.

If it lasts for ten years, nation states will collapse into anarchy. With hundreds of millions if not billions dead, international trade will grind to a halt, and countries will start running out of oil and fuel. Sure, there's still oil in the ground in Saudi Arabia, but the Saudis have starved to death because they can't import food, and you can't go get the oil because you don't have fuel for transport.

If it lasts for fifty years, the survivors are reduced to medieval technology. A hundred years, stone age technology. A millennium? There's a good chance of extinction.

No, civilization doesn't survive. Human beings might not even survive.

It's hard to tell whether the new "snowball climate" will be permanent or not. I suspect not: I'd be surprised if it lasted more than thirty or forty years, after which there would be five or ten reasonable years before the greenhouse effect rebounds. Either way, climate will change, permanently, and the few survivors will be scrambling to migrate to places with less hostile climate. And we all know just how welcoming frightened, hungry people are when strangers from the other side of the world, many of whom have different colour skin and speak different languages, suddenly rock up on your borders demanding to be let in.

If you want to know what a nuclear winter, or asteroid winter, would do, you could do a lot worse than watch "The Road" (real nightmare fuel). Or read David Brin's novel "The Postman" for an *optimistic* take on it.